# Cómo hacer consulta SQL con QuerySet de Django

Tags: sql, django, orm

Tengo que hacer una aplicación que construya un reporte personalizado por el cliente mediante variables seleccionadas desde el lado del cliente. Estoy usando Django 1.11 con BD SQL Server

La cuestión es que necesito armar un Query en función a las variables seleccionadas para consultarlo con mis modelos y enviar una respuesta al template y no encuentro la manera de armar este tipo de Querys con los QuerySet de Django.

Una consulta a procesar sería algo así:

```
SELECT Gerente.nombre_gte, Local.codigo, Alta.fecha_carga, Alta.cantidad, Homologador.homologado
FROM reporteria_alta Alta
INNER JOIN reporteria_local Local ON Local.gerente_id = Alta.local_key_id
INNER JOIN reporteria_gerente Gerente ON Gerente.id = Local.gerente_id
INNER JOIN reporteria_produccion_plan Produccion ON Produccion.id = Alta.plan_key_id
INNER JOIN reporteria_plan Planes ON Planes.id = Produccion.plan_id 
INNER JOIN reporteria_homologador Homologador ON Homologador.id = Planes.homologado_id
```

Pero no se como llevar esto a QuerySet y necesito alguna idea o colaboración.

Mis Modelos para el ejemplo son:

```
class Gerente(models.Model):
    nombre_gte = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    coordinador=models.ForeignKey(Coordinador,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activo=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.nombre_gte


class Local(models.Model):
    fecha =  models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nombre_local = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cc =  models.BooleanField(default=False)

    gerente=models.ForeignKey(Gerente,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    region=models.ForeignKey(Region,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    canal_venta=models.ForeignKey(Canal_Venta,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activo=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.codigo

class Homologador(models.Model):
    homologado=models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.homologado


class Plan(models.Model):
    codigo_plan=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    nombre_plan=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    homologado=models.ForeignKey(Homologador,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre_plan


class Produccion_Plan(models.Model):
    fecha =  models.DateField()
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    renta_mensual = models.FloatField()
    recarga_plan = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.plan


class Alta(models.Model):
    fecha_carga=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    fecha_actividad=models.DateField()
    plataforma=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    tecnologia=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    cantidad=models.IntegerField()
    plan_key=models.ForeignKey(Produccion_Plan,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    local_key=models.ForeignKey(Local,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return "ALTA %s Descrp: CodVend=%s Tecnolg=%s " %(self.cantidad, self.local_key,self.tecnologia)
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Los Join con QuerySet son bastantes sencillos, pero necesito saber que variables son las que podrá seleccionar  el cliente para los filtros

Comment: @Jimy Hendrix Falcón Cárdenas Te refieres al where del queryset ? Creo que esa es mi duda porque he intendado con `select_related` y con `values` colocando sus campos relacionados pero al aplicar el metodo `.query()` me retorna un query de tipo `SELECT .... FROM .... LEFT OUTER JOIN...` y lo que necesito es un simple `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Respondiendo a tu pregunta, la variables asumo que son las fechas, ejemplo, necesito los Locales, Gerentes y Planes de una fecha especifica indicada por el usuario

Answer (score 0):

el `.query()` lo que hace es mostrarte el código SQL que se esta ejecutando, con haacer lo siguiente ya se hará la consulta (nuestro amigo django se encarga):

```
locales = Local.objects.filter(fecha='15-01-2018')
```

ese código se encargara de  hacer las consultas necesarias y te devuelve los registros de los locales  que tengan esa fecha e incluye los datos de sus tablas relacionadas, lo unico que tendrás que hacer en enviar "locales" al template y dentro de un for acceder de la siguiente manera a los valores:

```
{% for local in locales %}
     {{local.nombre_local}}, {{local.gerente.nombre_gte}}, {{local.alta.plan_key.plan.plan_nombre}} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

con respecto al "plan" tengo dudas al estar a un tercer nivel relacional con respecto a local, pero prueba esto y si tienes problemas me escribes.
Saludos

Comment: Ya conocía la funcionalidad del `.query()` y precisamente para eso lo usaba, para verificar si la sintaxis SQL estaba haciendo lo que yo quería. También conocía el método `.filter()` sin embargo desconocía que al hacer un queryset con este método se devolvía toda la información relacionada al modelo como me estas diciendo. Si es asi es de gran ayuda, lo voy a probar y te comento. Gracias!!!!

Comment: Genial! Me alegro haberte sido de ayuda.